# Displaying Facebook comments count with <fb:comments-count> tag

Tags: facebook

On the Facebook Developer page they say the comments counts can be displayed using

```
<fb:comments-count href=http://example.com/></fb:comments-count> awesome comments
```

I added this to my loop then:

```
<fb:comments-count href=<?php the_permalink();?>></fb:comments-count>
```

to display the comments count per each post.

Nothing is displayed even though I do have comments...any suggestion?

Thank you

Edit: placing the code in single.php, it shows the number 0 despite I have many comments....

Answer (score 1):

You need to include their [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) in order to utilize fbml.

FBML is also [deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/) for use of xFBML.

In this case, i would just recommend picking a wordpress / facebook plugin for what you need to do. As what you're trying to do in code isn't that simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Facebook plugin on my WordPress site. I put the code below on the loop and single.php page to show the number of comments

Comment: Which code? And are you telling us that it works, or are you asking for help? (If help, this ought to be a new question instead.)

Comment: However if you're asking about a specific Facebook plugin then you should talk to its authors instead - they'll know their own plugin better than we do to help you.